# How to manage with log in to the page when this step is required for each test

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for some proper solution how to manage with log in step to application before running each test. May I create LoginTest which would be initialized before each test or each class?

First thing which I did it was to add some steps to [TestInitialize]:
 SamplePage.GoTo(); SamplePage.FillOutFormAndSubmit(TheTestUser);

```
public class BaseTest
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupForEverySingleTestMethod()
    {
        var factory = new WebDriverFactory();
        Driver = factory.Create(BrowserType.IExplorer);
        SamplePage = new SampleLoginPage(Driver);
        TheTestUser = new TestUser();
        TheTestUser.UserName = "xxx";
        TheTestUser.Password = "xxx";
        SamplePage.GoTo();
        SamplePage.FillOutFormAndSubmit(TheTestUser);
    }
}
```

Is it a better way to implement log in to page, or maybe is more proper to use [ClassInitialize] to not waste a time for log in and quit after every single test.

Comment: If you need to log in before every test, then `TestInitialize` is the right place for it (although `GoTo` and `FillOutFormAndSubmit` should be in a separate test, unless you want them done every time). Use `ClassInitialize` if you can log in once for all tests.

Comment: Is any benefit with using e.g. NUnit instead of MS?

Comment: Not for this sort of thing, but I think NUnit has a few more options in `Assert`. Personally I chose to use NUnit because it appears in lots of job adverts, so it seemed like a useful skill!

Comment: If I would use those tests in CI in TFS e.g. in build does NUnit is still a good choice?

Comment: I think so. We use it and have no complaints. We've not tried all the alternatives but it seems to be the most popular. We used to have a mix of MS and NUnit tests, and the differences were small. It was easy to convert when we decided to standardise, so I wouldn't worry about it too much. The most important thing is to build experience of writing and maintaining tests.